# How to allow only iPhone 4 to use app since it uses front camera

Tags: iphone, xcode, camera

I was wondering how to only let iPhone 4 use my app which uses the front camera. 
Can I do a  `+ (BOOL)isCameraDeviceAvailable:(UIImagePickerControllerCameraDevice)`
and how do I implement it so that it gives some sort of error if it returns no

or do I have to a NSString *DeviceType etc..

if iPhone 4 ... 
do nothing

if else ... Display alert?

How do I implement that in my app?

TIA!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could add `front-facing-camera` to `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` in your `Info.plist`. That way the app won't run without front camera and your users won't be able to download it from the App Store without an iPhone 4.

Comment: Ah! That works too! I assume apple will allow it that way too!

Answer (score 5):

Put this in your app delegate's `applicationDidFinishLaunching` method:

```
if (![UIImagePickerController isCameraDeviceAvailable: UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront])
{
     [[[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"No Front Camera" 
                                  message: @"This app requires a front camera." 
                                 delegate: self 
                        cancelButtonTitle: @"Ok" 
                        otherButtonTitles: nil] autorelease] show];
}
```

Comment: Okay. Sorry to be a total noob, but where do I declare it?

Comment: See my code above... the `UIImagePickerControllerSourceType` is passed into the `+isCameraDeviceAvailable` method.  The You should have a `applicationDidFinishLaunching` in your app delegate.  This question may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245390/nsapplication-and-applicationdidfinishlaunching

Comment: I got this working, but it's [UIImagePickerController isCameraDeviceAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront] -- not UIImagePickerViewController.  Thanks!

Comment: @Jeffrey Berthiaume: Thanks for catching that typo... updated the answer.